# renaming a collection with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I can not rename a collection in mongoDB. I can see that it exists and can write and read data from it. I have attempted the following using the node mongo native driver.

```
db.collection("mycollection").renameCollection("mynewcollection");

error: TypeError: Object #<Collection> has no method 'renameCollection'
```

and

```
db['mycollection'].renameCollection("mynewcollection");

Cannot call method 'renameCollection' of undefined
```

performing the following in the same place returns all docs as expected

```
db.collection("mycollection").find({}).toArray(function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `db.mycollection.renameCollection("mynewcollection");`?[Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/)

Comment: yeah, it is the same as the first solution but I have still tried both syntax's

Comment: I think you need the `rename` [method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#rename)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The method to rename a collection using the node.js driver is [`rename`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#rename), not `renameCollection`:

```
db.collection("mycollection").rename("mynewcollection", function(err, newColl) {...});
```

Comment: @wazzaday For what it's worth, they named it that way because the dot chaining syntax already puts you in the context of a collection. It's easier in plain English to read "collection.rename", but more redundant to read "collection.renameCollection". They tried to make the API more intuitive that way.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your collection.js (it should be added to line 153, or endof the collection.js code) , it should resolve the problem.

```
req.collection.rename(name, function(err, collection) {
     if (err) {
-      req.session.error('Something went wrong: ' + err);
+      req.session.error = 'Something went wrong: ' + err;
       console.error(err);
       return res.redirect('back');
     }

     req.updateCollections(req.db, req.dbName, function(err) {
       if (err) {
-        req.session.error('Something went wrong: ' + err);
+        req.session.error = 'Something went wrong: ' + err;
         return res.redirect('back');
       }

-      req.session.success('Collection renamed!');
+      req.session.success = 'Collection renamed!';
       res.redirect(config.site.baseUrl+'db/' + req.dbName + '/' + name);
     });
   });
```